# How do you modify the modal height without removing the slide effect in Bootstrap Twitter?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've modified how far down the modal is but now the sliding down effect from adding the `fade` class is not working anymore.  Is there a way to get the sliding effect working with changing the top distance?

html:

```
<div id='test-modal' class='modal fade hide'>
  <div>Stuff</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#test-modal.modal {
  top:35%;
}
```

jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Kcnq4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you add `.fade.in` with your class then fade in effect will remain there.

```
#test-modal.modal.fade.in {
    top:35%;
}​
```

you can test it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mbilal/Kcnq4/3/).